# How to use condition in Makefile.am

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

from configure.ac I have set variable ALSA=1 or nothing

```
./configure --enable-alsa=yes
or
./configure //nothing
```

and I need add source code alsa.c to Makefile.am:

```
__abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES+=alsa.c
```

I tried:
Makefile.am:

```
__abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES=main.c some.c anothercode.c
if ALSA
     __abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES+=alsa.c
else
     __abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES+=somethingelse.c
endif
```

and it creates
Makefile.in ending with

```
@ALSA_TRUE@     __abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES += \
@ALSA_TRUE@     alsa.c
@ALSA_FALSE@    __abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES += \
@ALSA_FALSE@    somethingelse.c
```

and Makefile ending with:

```
#       __abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES += \
#       alsa.c
        __abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES += \
        somethingelse.c
```

but I need this rows on top of this file with other source code files, because this Makefile doesn't work. I hope you understand me :)

and related part of configure.ac:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(alsa,
  AS_HELP_STRING(
    [--enable-alsa],
    [enable alsa, default: no]),
    [case "${enableval}" in
      yes)  alsa=true ;;
      no)   alsa=false ;;
      *)   AC_MSG_ERROR([bad value ${enableval} for --enable-alsa]) ;;
    esac],
    [alsa=false])
AM_CONDITIONAL(ALSA, test x"$alsa" = x"true")
AM_COND_IF(ALSA, 
    AC_DEFINE(ALSA, 1, [Define to 0 for Something else]),[])
```

What is it wrong? May I use ALSA variable like that?Thanks you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
__abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES=main.c some.c anothercode.c
if ALSA
     __abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES+=alsa.c
else
     __abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES+=somethingelse.c
endif
```

to this:

```
__abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES=main.c some.c anothercode.c
if ALSA
__abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES+=alsa.c
else
__abs_top_srcdir__bin_myprogram_SOURCES+=somethingelse.c
endif
```

and it should work.

BTW, your're also making the code in `configure.ac` overly complex.  This'll do the same thing:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(alsa,
  AS_HELP_STRING(
    [--enable-alsa],
    [enable alsa, default: no]))
AM_CONDITIONAL([ALSA], [test "x$enable_alsa" = "xyes"])
AM_COND_IF([ALSA],
    [AC_DEFINE(ALSA, 1, [Define to 0 for Something else])],[])
```